# Pronouncing Greek words

Tags: vba, text-to-speech

I'm currently trying to add a TTS function for a text box in my application (by using the `.Speak` method). My problem is that when it comes to Greek characters, the word is spelled instead of being pronounced (for example: Κωστας (Kostas) is pronounced as  "Kapa - Omicron - Sigma - Ta - Alpha - Sigma " instead of simply "Kostas" ).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the second sign really spelled as "Omicron"? In `Κωστας` ? This looks like a critical business issue to me ...

Comment: Ι convert "ω" to "ο" because "ω" can't be pronounced at all (sound-wise, it's the same) .

Comment: Are you with Greek regional settings or with English/American one's?

Comment: Btw, I do not see any Greek language here - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-the-speak-feature-with-multilingual-tts-e522a4f2-37cb-492b-be6a-8997d23dfe70, thus most probably it is simply following some Math language. Is `B` pronounced Beta or Vita in your Excel?

Comment: Like others have addressed: What is your regional settings?

Comment: Regional settings are Greek, @Vityata Β is pronounced as Beta

Comment: @AlkoPi - Long story short - you can achieve it once Greek appears to be in this list - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-the-speak-feature-with-multilingual-tts-e522a4f2-37cb-492b-be6a-8997d23dfe70 Until then it cannot be done. Once it is in the list, there would be actors with male/female voices, who do it professionally. See the other (non-English) languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The letters are pronounced separately following the Erasmus pronounsiation, because this is how they are used in other languages as Maths/Physics symbols. Obviously Greek is not in the supported languages for `TextToSpeech` ([source Support.Office.Com](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-the-speak-feature-with-multilingual-tts-e522a4f2-37cb-492b-be6a-8997d23dfe70)):

- Chinese (Hong Kong)
- Chinese (PRC)
- Chinese (Taiwan)
- Danish (Denmark)
- Dutch (Netherlands)
- English (Australia)
- English (Canada)
- English (India)
- English (United Kingdom)
- English (United States)
- Finnish (Finland)
- French (Canada)
- French (France)
- German (Germany)
- Italian (Italy)
- Japanese (Japan)
- Korean (Korea)
- Norwegian (Norway)
- Polish (Poland)
- Portuguese (Brazil)
- Portuguese (Portugal)
- Russian (Russia)
- Spanish (Catalan)
- Spanish (Mexico)
- Spanish (Spain)
- Swedish (Sweden)